# Need Google Script to copy values from one tab to another

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I am working on scorecards for my business. Employees receive different Paid Time Off based on their length of employment. I need a script that copies only the values from the employee's "master" scorecard to new sheet titled the current month. Because their PTO changes, I need a script that will copy that information to a new tab so that the original does not continue changing PTO scores as length of employment continues.

I have created the bottom script which does everything except it also copies over all the formulas that make the PTO scores change as time goes on. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
function Copymastersheettoscorecard(){
var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-22", "MM/dd/yyyy");
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1hkmRbHD24X1y8yJFdbd-BPaSyctyHGvyQBy9mi4mDc8"); 
var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ooGOPyXLYJrcN0WFH2d65hOODj_Z4DtZu47E6a04VHs");
var Newsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Sheet").copyTo(dss).setName(date); 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several options:

- 1. Copy the sheet to the new spreadsheet, and then use a combination of [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange), [setValues(values)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) and [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues) to remove the formulas:

```
function Copymastersheettoscorecard(){
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-22", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID_1");
  var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID_2");
  var Newsheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master Sheet").copyTo(dss).setName(date);
  var destRange = Newsheet.getDataRange();
  destRange.setValues(destRange.getValues());
}
```

- 2. Insert and empty sheet in the new spreadsheet, and copy the values from the original sheet directly, also using `getDataRange`, `setValues` and `getValues`:

```
function Copymastersheettoscorecard(){
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-22", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID_1");
  var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID_2");
  var Newsheet = dss.insertSheet(date);
  var sourceValues = ss.getSheetByName("Master Sheet").getDataRange().getValues();
  Newsheet.getRange(1,1,sourceValues.length,sourceValues[0].length).setValues(sourceValues);
}
```

This second method is less complex, but it won't copy over the formatting. Don't use this is you want to keep that.

- 3. Use [Range.copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-copypastetype,-transposed), which allows to set the option to paste only values (`SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES`). This way, though, would require creating and deleting a temporary Sheet (since it cannot be used to copy ranges between different spreadsheets), and it wouldn't keep the formatting either:

```
function Copymastersheettoscorecard(){
  var date = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT-22", "MM/dd/yyyy");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID_1");
  var dss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS_ID_2");
  var sourceRange = ss.getSheetByName("Master Sheet").getDataRange();
  var Tempsheet = ss.insertSheet("TEMPORARY");
  sourceRange.copyTo(Tempsheet.getRange("A1"), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
  Tempsheet.copyTo(dss).setName(date);
  ss.deleteSheet(Tempsheet);
}
```